# Transcendence degree and Krull dimension of finitely generated algebras

Tags: commutative-algebra, finitely-generated, krull-dimension, transcendence-degree

Let $K$ be a field, and let $a_1,\dots,a_{n+1}$ be $n+1$ elements of a finitely generated $K$-algebra $A$ of Krull dimension $n$.

> Are the elements $a_1,\dots,a_{n+1}$ always algebraically dependent over $K$?

I.e: Are the monomials $(a_1)^{m_1}\cdots(a_{n+1})^{m_{n+1}}$ always $K$-linearly dependent?

The answer is Yes if $A$ is a domain. Indeed, in this case, $n$ is the transcendence degree of $L$ over $K$, where $L$ is the field of fractions of $A$.

[The $K$-algebra $A$ is assumed to be commutative and unital.]

Comment: If $A'\subset A$ is a finitely generated $K$-subalgebra, then $\dim A'\le\dim A$.

Comment: @user26857 - Do you mean that it's a consequence of Slup's answer? Or do you have a direct argument to prove your statement?

Comment: I mean that this is a general result which has as an immediate consequence an answer to your question.

Comment: @user26857 - Very interesting! Could you give me a reference for this general result? What is the argument you have in mind to prove it?

Comment: This can be proved by a similar argument to the one in the answer below. A reference is e.g. Corollary 3.2 from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.1391).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is a finitely generated algebra over $k$ of Krull dimension $n$. Assume that $k[x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1}]$ is a polynomial subalgebra of $A$. Pick $S = k[x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1}]\setminus \{0\}$. This is a multiplicative subset of $A$. Hence there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ such that
$$\mathfrak{p}\cap S = \emptyset$$
Now consider $B = A/\mathfrak{p}$. Then $B$ is a finitely generated domain over $k$ of Krull dimension $\leq n$. Moreover, $B$ contains polynomial $k$-subalgebra in $n+1$ variables (image of $k[x_1,...,x_{n+1}]$ under the surjection $A\rightarrow B$). This is a contradiction.

Comment: The answer is fine. (+1)