# Krull dimesion and algebraic independence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

**Edit:** It really is impossible! Found the answer here: [Transcendence degree and Krull dimension of finitely generated algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504001/transcendence-degree-and-krull-dimension-of-finitely-generated-algebras?rq=1) . But I'm not deleting my question because the linked question was hard to find, and maybe my wording will help future people searching.

**The question:**

1. Let $k$ be a field (not necessarily algebraically closed).
2. Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra generated by $x_1,...,x_n$ (not necessarily an integral domain).
3. Assume that $A$ has Krull dimension $d<n$.

> Is it then possible that $x_1,...,x_{d+1}$ are algebraically independent over $k$?

I think it's impossible.

If $A$ is an intergral domain then I get that the field of fractions of $A$ has transcendence degree at least $d+1$ over $k$, a contradiction.

But I'm not assuming that $A$ is an integral domain.

If $k$ is algebraically closed, then the injective map $k[x_1,...,x_{d+1}]\to k[x_1,...,x_n]$ induces a dominant map from $\operatorname{maxspec}(A)$ to $\mathbb{A}_k^{d+1}$, and I think that's a contradiction again.

But what happens generally? My geometric argument probably generalizes to the case where $k$ is not algebraically closed, but I'm don't know the needed facts. Also, I'd like to have an algebraic proof (but a geometric one is fine too).